# JQuery and Razor Controller View ActionResult

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a controller who can return a Success or Error page like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult File_post(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   if (...)
      return View("Success");
   else
      return View("Error");
}
```

Those Success and Error pages contains only basic text and are displayed in the Shared/_Layout.cshtml.

In my js I want to call those pages defined by the return View, but how can I do that ?

I tested : `window.location.reload();`
Which works but it only reloads the actual Index page.
If I try : `window.location.href = data.url;`
It fails because the page **http://xxx/xxx/File_post** doesn't exists.
And if I do : `$('#main').html(data);`
The page have the good looking but the content is empty.

**Edit:** I am using jquery.fileupload so I have :

```
 <input id="fileupload" type="file" name="file" />
```

and

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
{
  done: function (e, data) {
    // Use the return View("Success")
  },
  fail: function (e, data) {
    // Use the return View("Error")
  }
});
```

In my jqXHR.reponseText and data.result there is the good "Success" or "Error" html so I think I need to fill the page with this but how ?

Any ideas ? thanks a lot !

Comment: File_post is not an ajax call, or is it?  When does done get called?  That's where I'm a little confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found how to do it.
As I have in my Layout a `<div id="main">`
I can use my data.result to fill the page with my "Success" or "Error" message.
So I have :

```
done: function (e, data) {
  $('#main').html(data.result);
}
```

And

```
return PartialView("Success");
```

Now the page is correctly displayed.

Comment: Yes, as I will comment "if you want the html JS detected in differentiating a message ´Success´ or ´Error´, you have to find some data in the HTML response". But in your example, you wanted to put the results obtained in the event ´done´ and ´fail´. For that you have to specify a different exit status ´200´

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

```
$.ajax({
 type: "POST",
 url: Settings.YourUrl,
 data: "{queryString:'" + searchVal + "'}",
 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 dataType: "html",
 success: function (data) {
 alert("here" + data.d.toString());
});
```

And in your View you can add this code

```
var Settings= {
    YourUrl: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The current action can handle only POST requests. So you can create another action to return the view for GET request.

Ex.

```
public ViewResult Success()
{
   return View();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can changed the statusCode to 500 or error code you need;

C#

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult File_post(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
   if (...) 
   {
      return View("Success");
   }
   else
   {
      Response.StatusCode = 500;
      Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true; 
      return View("Error");
   }
}
```

JS:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload(
{
  done: function (e, data) {
    // Use the return View("Success")
  },
  fail: function (e, data) { // http status response != 200
    // Use the return View("Error")
  }
});
```

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, I don't know how to go to the Success or Error page in my js because when I use the js the page it seems that the return View(...) doesn't work. Before I was not using the js and only calling the File_post with a button and it was working well.

Comment: in JS, you do not have to do anything, the plugin has to detect that there is a error status and have to call the function passed to the option "fail". if you want the html JS detected in differentiating a message "Success" or "Error", you have to find some data in the HTML response.

Comment: The detection of "done" and "fail" is done correctly. In my jqXHR the reponse text contains the good "Success" or "Error" html so I think I need to fill the page with this.